# Cannot access database after pgadmin upgrade - encryption error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I had been using an older version of pgadmin - version 4.2 - I finally upgraded to 4.12 and now am having a strange problem with not been able to connect to just 1 DB.

I have upgraded from pgadmin 4.2 to 4.12 on a Windows server Azure VM.  I understand there's added security,  but now I think I got a corrupted password or something.  I have 1 server and 3 DBs on that server (not including the default postgres db).  The DBs were all created the same way (the pgadmin 4.2 UI and schemas/tables created with Flyway) and are very similar (just different versions of the same DB actually).  I can still access 2 of them, but the 3rd is giving the error below.  As a test, I found another VM that had a very old version of pgadmin (3.x) and I can connect to this DB from there.  So, I know the DB is OK and the password still works with an older pgadmin.

The error is:

```
Failed to decrypt the saved password.
Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

How can I access this DB using pgadmin 4.12?  Worst case, if I really needed to, I could drop and recreate the DB, but I'd really rather not.  Even so, I wouldn't be able to drop it from here and I don't know if I recreate it with the same name (which is has to be) if this pgadmin installation would still be confused.

One last thing, the password was just letters and numbers, this is a development/testing DB and had a medium to lower strength password, so whatever is causing this error is not due to some crazy complex password.

I am a developer, not a DBA, and really don't know any tricks or ways around this...  Any assistance is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I can't clear saved passwords - those options do not show in the context menu and are greyed out in the Object menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the stored password, Follow the steps mentioned here

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.12/clear_saved_passwords.html

Once stored passwords are clear you will be able to access your DB again.

Comment: Thank you but those options are greyed out for me.

Comment: you need to select the respective server in the browser tree then you can use this option

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to completely remove all traces of pgadmin4 from the VM and reinstall it.  That seemed to work.  I guess the initial installation got corrupted somehow.

Thanks.